# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'emlpoyee' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, illegalstateexception

I do know, that similar question was raised here several times, however all those posts didn't help me and I still fail to fix it.

Here is part of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/contacts") 
@Controller 
public class ContactController {
final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactController.class); 

@Autowired
private ContactService contactService;

@Autowired 
MessageSource messageSource;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String updateForm(@PathVariable ("id") Long id, Model uiModel) { 
    uiModel.addAttribute("employee", employeeService.findById(id)); 
    logger.info("Updating employee form, id: " + id);       

    return "staff/update";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String update(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, BindingResult  bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Locale locale) { 

logger.info("Updating employee");
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) { 
    uiModel.addAttribute("message", new Message("error", messageSource.getMessage("employee_save_fail", new Object[]{}, locale))); 
uiModel.addAttribute("employee", employee);

return "staff/update"; 
}

uiModel.asMap().clear(); 
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", new Message("success", messageSource.getMessage("employee_save_success", new Object[]{}, locale)));
employeeService.update(employee); 

return "redirect:/staff/" + UrlUtil.encodeUrlPathSegment(employee.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest); 
}
```

Here is part of my edit.jspx:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="emlpoyee" id="employeeUpdateForm" method="post">
    <c:if test="${not empty message}"> 
        <div id="message" class="${message.type}">${message.message}</div> 
    </c:if> 

    <form:hidden path="firstName" />
    <form:hidden path="lastName" /> 
    <form:hidden path="salary" /> 
    <form:hidden path="birthDate" /> 
    <form:hidden path="departmentId" /> 
    <form:hidden path="active" /> 

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form:form>
```

Whatever if put there form:input path=.... or form:label path=.... tags, the result would be the same :(.

Supplementary classes Message and UrlUtil are simple and straightforward.
Employee class has all required getters and setters, and their have correct names and signatures.

updateForm method works just fine.

When I comment all those form:hidden tags it starts working properly, I get screen with two buttons... But actually I need to have number of inputs there.

I would be grateful for any kind help or assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form:form modelAttribute="emlpoyee"
```

should be

```
<form:form modelAttribute="employee"
```

surely?

Comment: Thank you TrueDub!!!  You have saved me hours. It is all due to lack of attention. Thought I I would go mad.